# Pandas dataframe only keeps last value in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the code below, and then my code output. Does anybody know why a, b, c variables are not keeping their values??

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

for i in range(3):
    df.loc[0] = [i, i, i]
    if i == 0:
        a = df
        print "Printing a inside of the loop:"
        print a
    elif i == 1:
        b = df
        print "Printing b inside of the loop:"
        print b
    elif i == 2:
        c = df
        print "Printing c inside of the loop:"
        print c

print "Printing a outside of the loop:"
print a
print "Printing b outside of the loop:"
print b
print "Printing c outside of the loop:"
print c
```

Code output:
[image]

Comment: try a=df.copy(), otherwise a and df are the same object

Comment: You are passing the same dataframe as a reference, to have different values, you should copy them using `copy()`, as in `a = df.copy()`

Comment: `a = df` does NOT make a new copy of df.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is that `a,b,c` aren't actually separate variables.

The way Python works under-the-hood means that why you say `a = df`, Python makes a *reference* to `df`, so `a` actually points at the same underlying memory as `df` - it's basically just another name for the same variable.

That means what you're doing here is overwriting the numbers in `df` for each iteration of the loop, then when you read back the values in `a`, `b` and `c`, you're just reading the data that's sitting in `df`.

What you actually need is a true copy of the dataframe, using (e.g.) `a = df.copy()`.